# Best way to hide WordPress page title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am completely new to this and am trying to learn on my own.  One thing I am having an issue on finding a solution to is how to hide the page title on a WP site.  I have read that leaving the page title blank, although solving the issue, may not be good in terms of SEO, so I would like to hide page titles instead.

I have tried using multiple plugins, all with no luck.  Additionally, I have tried adding additional CSS code both to hide specific page titles and titles across the entire site.

The code I have been using is

```
.entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
.page-id-XXX .entry-title {
    display: none;
}
```

None seem to work.  Additionally, I tried to see if my theme has an option, and it doesn't.

Is anyone able to let me know what I may be doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Solving this is very theme specific. You need to give a link to the website of name of the theme so that someone can attempt to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you sir!  Do you mind if I PM you?

Comment: I don't think you can PM me on stackoverflow. You can mail me, find the email ID on my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below to hide header.

```css
.header-page {
   display : none;
}
```

---

This will work when the header has class `.header-page`.

This CSS should go inside every page where you want to hide, if its site-wide add it on head.

```html
<style>
.header-page {
   display : none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @greenascanbe, As this worked, I would recommend you to mark this answer as correct. You can do that like this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1004134